# Computing conditional probaility: population Spearman rank correlation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, spearman-rho

Let $Z$ and $U$ are independent random variable distributed over $[0,\infty]$ and  $(0,1)$ respectively. We also assume $S$ and $T$ are identically distributed random variable over $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Let us denote $V=Z(U(S-T)+T)$ and $W=\frac{US}{Z(U(S-T)+T)}$.

What is the value of Spearman rank correlation $\rho$, where,  $$\rho=2P(V_1<V_3/W_1<W_2<W_3)-1$$ for three iid pairs $(V_1,W_1),(V_2,W_2)$ and $(V_3,W_3)$?

**Tried**:  From identicallity of the distribution we get :$P(W_1<W_2<W_3)=1/6$. Now we want to compute $\rho=P(V_1<V_3,W_1<W_2<W_3)$. How to compute?

THANKS....